# Need to re-enter route after each reboot or network restart on CentOS

Tags: networking, centos

I was told by network admins to run this command to get my network working properly on centos.

```
​route add 198.245.49.254 dev eth0
route add default gw 198.245.49.254
```

After adding it, I could ping and traceroute domains. However now each time I reboot or restart network, it needs to run again. Is there a work-around for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For a CentOS system, use the `system-config-network` utility to configure your network settings. Enter the default gateway there.

Those route statements seem redundant.

Can you post the output of `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn` from your system when things are working?

Comment: I ran system-config-network and setting on there seem to be correct.

Here are the outputs for netstat -rn and ifconfig http://pastebin.com/K2KedLEF and http://pastebin.com/rfkV7hdr

Comment: That's a new one... hand a client a /32 address and make him manually add routes to reach the rest of the network...  If this is hosted, I would find a different (clueful) hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Those "admins" should be ashamed. I don't know CentOS thus I cannot give you the exact steps with the distro tool but without doubt you can configure a default gateway.

Without a distro tool you may solve the problem by editing the file `/etc/sysconfig/network/routes`.

Comment: How many NICs are installed? One? Two?